# Pre-warm disk cache

Tags: windows, io

After some theoretical discussion today I decided to do some research, but I did not find anything conclusive.

Here's the problem:
We have written a tool that reads around 10Gb of image files from a data set of several terabytes. We want to speed up the execution time by minimizing I/O overhead. The idea would be to "pre-warm" the disk cache, as we known beforehand what directory we will be reading from as the tool executes. Is there any API or method to give this hint to Windows so that it can start pre-warming the disk cache, speeding up future disk access as the files are already in RAM (of which there is plenty on the machines we run the tool on)?

I know Windows does readahead on a single file, but what if I have a directory with thousands of files?

I haven't found any direct win32 APIs or command line tools to do this directly.

What if I start a low priority background thread, opening all the files for reading and closing them?
I could of course memory map all the files and pin them in RAM, but that would probably run the risk of starving the main worker thread of I/O.

The general idea here is that the tool "bursts" I/O requests, as each thread will do I/O and CPU processing in sequence, hence we could use the "idle" I/O time to preload the remaining files into RAM.

(I could of course benchmark, and I will, but I would like to understand a bit more of  how this works in order to be more scientific and less cargo culty).